# Best approach for reusing code laravel 5

Tags: laravel, module, laravel-5, hmvc

I'm new to Laravel, in codeigniter we can use something like HMVC to make our code modular and reusable. what is the best approach in laravel? for example lets say i created a artwork gallery, how can i use it in my next projects as a module?

Comment: so is it possible to create something within laravel architecture, then with composer use it in other laravel project? is there any example or documentation about this  approach?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/packages Also I'm sure you'll find tutorials online on how to develop a composer package. It's pretty simple...

Comment: you can create trait in laravel modular structure and use it.